# Consumer Expenditures by Census Tract

Tags: uses-of-open-data, us-census, census, spending

Does anyone know how to source Consumer Expenditures (CEX) by Census Tract?

I know that the Bureau of Labor Statistics offers CEX by Metropolitan Area and Region but I can't seem to figure out how to get the data by Census Tract.

Comment: hi, the sample size of the consumer expenditure survey isn't sufficient to make small area estimates

Comment: @AnthonyDamico thanks. How do you think ESRI and ZoomProspector are able to get CEX down to smaller boundary areas?

Comment: hi, what do their methods docs say?